# Notepad ++ : sample text occurences within a file <s>number of occurrences of a text below and above a certain line number</s>

Tags: notepad++

I open a server log file with Notepad++ and search for a certain string. The `count` button tells me there are over 100 occurrences. While I could use the `Find next` button, sometimes I would really like to just jump to a certain line and know how many occurrences are above and below that certain line.

Is there any functionality/plugin that can achieve the following:

**- while being at line L, to display me how many occurrences of a string are above/below that line**

**- navigate directly to the N-th occurrence  of that string within the file**

This functionality would be helpful, as I analyze error messages. Sometimes the error messages are identical all over the file, sometimes there are slight variations - so I search for the root of the message and I would really like to sample the 10th, 20th, 30th (and so on) occurrence of that message, instead of clicking 10 or 20 times on the Next button.

(maybe it's unimportant, but the log file has more than 10,000 lines)

Comment: An obvious workaround for *your first question* would be to delete the lines below/above the line L and retry the search.

Comment: It could be a good idea otherwise, but in my situation it is impractical for two reasons: 1. I have thousands of lines of text, and deleting them (even selecting them) takes a lot of time. 2. I need to perform this operation many times (this operation is linked to a repeated search operation), so deleting text and undoing many times also takes a lot of time, and is error prone

Comment: I'm unaware of any plugin which can do either of those two functions, but I agree it would be useful. You can kind of get the functionality you asked for in your second point by clicking **Find All in Current Document** in the **Find** dialog. This'll open the **Find result** panel which displays every occurrence of the string on a new line. Double click any line to jump to it in your main window. (10,000 lines and over 100 occurrences is fine. It handles my 17MiB, 72,000 line log with 100+ occurrences effortlessly - [link](https://imgur.com/a/qk3rtTV))

Comment: @GordonAitchJay: please post it as an answer. That is exactly what I was looking for. What I wanted was a way to sample the occurrences of a text, and I asked for those hypothetical plugin functionalities; but this is even better, as I can scroll all the occurrences, and I can get an approximate idea of the distribution of the text within the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kind of get the functionality you asked for in your second point by clicking **Find All in Current Document in the Find dialog**. This will open the **Find result** panel which displays every occurrence of the string on a new line. Double click any line to jump to it in your main window.

(10,000 lines and over 100 occurrences is fine. It handles my 17MiB, 72,000 line log with 100+ occurrences effortlessly)

[image: Notepad++ Find dialog]